# How to use GStreamer to send and receive a RTSP feed on same computer in Windows

Tags: windows, opencv, command-line, streaming, gstreamer

I am trying to send Opencv images over the network. I was suggested to use GStreamer for that purpose.

I have installed GStreamer and now testing it on my Windows 10.

I am able to display test video using the following command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

Now I try to send video using RTSP. For now, I want to stream my desktop using GStreamer and watch it in VLC. For sending the video I am using:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v gdiscreencapsrc  ! queue  ! videoconvert !  video/x-raw,format=I420 ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! queue ! udpsink host=172.16.15.147 port=8554
```

For which response is:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstGDIScreenCapSrc:gdiscreencapsrc0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)30/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)30/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)30/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)30/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)I420
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)30/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)I420
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstJpegEnc:jpegenc0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)30/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)I420
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)30/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)I420
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoConvert:videoconvert0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)30/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstJpegEnc:jpegenc0.GstPad:src: caps = image/jpeg, sof-marker=(int)0, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)bt709, chroma-site=(string)mpeg2
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJPEGPay:rtpjpegpay0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)JPEG, a-framerate=(string)30.000000, payload=(int)26, ssrc=(uint)665894884, timestamp-offset=(uint)2085395382, seqnum-offset=(uint)6071
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue1.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)JPEG, a-framerate=(string)30.000000, payload=(int)26, ssrc=(uint)665894884, timestamp-offset=(uint)2085395382, seqnum-offset=(uint)6071
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue1.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)JPEG, a-framerate=(string)30.000000, payload=(int)26, ssrc=(uint)665894884, timestamp-offset=(uint)2085395382, seqnum-offset=(uint)6071
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue1.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)JPEG, a-framerate=(string)30.000000, payload=(int)26, ssrc=(uint)665894884, timestamp-offset=(uint)2085395382, seqnum-offset=(uint)6071
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)JPEG, a-framerate=(string)30.000000, payload=(int)26, ssrc=(uint)665894884, timestamp-offset=(uint)2085395382, seqnum-offset=(uint)6071
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJPEGPay:rtpjpegpay0: timestamp = 2085395391
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJPEGPay:rtpjpegpay0: seqnum = 6294
```

But I am unable to watch it on VLC using rtsp://172.16.15.147:8554

I even tried sending it to 127.0.0.1:5000

How to know I am even sending the packet? I tried capturing packets on Wireshark but it's not useful.

Please suggest a method to send and receive stream using GStreamer on same PC.

Comment: `udpsink` != `RTSP` To do RTSP you have to use something like https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server

Comment: @RSATom it's true that udpsink is different from rtsp, but the element used right before the udpsink, rtpjpegpay, packages the encoded JPEG image into RTP packets, which is suitable to be sent via UDP, kinda giving the same effect in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, you need a **.sdp** file.

This is the minimum your SDP file must contain

```
v=<version>
c=IN IP4 <IP4 ADDRESS>
m=<media> <udp port> RTP/AVP <payload>
a=rtpmap:<payload> <encoding-name>/<clock-rate>
```

I just tested on a stream from a camera I have at home that
happens to have very similar parameters to yours, you'll just need
to change the IP address:

```
v=0
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.188
m=video 5200 RTP/AVP 26
a=rtpmap:26 JPEG/90000
```

Then the following command will just work

```
vlc stuff.sdp
```

Comment: I tried that already and it didn't work. Finally, I end up using gst-rtsp-server.